# jQuery multimedia embedding out of sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a company web page and we have the need to embed some video information for our clients. These videos will be tutorials on how to use our products.

There are 3 issues that I'm having with this web page
 1. Resizing the borders of the window will cause the background to flicker.
 2. When a video is playing, the user is able to click the drop down box and select a new video which loads, but the audio from the original remains playing.
 3. I've also noticed that these videos take some time to load. The videos are around 40 megs in size but the same videos play instantly when loaded directly from our server and not played through a web browser (which attepts to embed the very same videos)

Here are our hardware specifications:
Browser: Internet Explorer 8 (We cannot upgrade to 9 for a while still married to 8 for now.)
Server: Ibm i5 520

The work stations are all x86 machines wired directly into our server via ethernet cable.
I'm new to jQuery and mostly program in C++ so this stateless programming has been a headache.

I've hosted the file below.
http://pastebin.com/bdFqX6xd

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to start with html video:

http://videojs.com/

Great piece of js to get videos imbedded and also has good instructions.